# Find the cumulative function and the density of $m_n$ and $M_n$, where $m_n=\min(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ and $M_n=\max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let be $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be uniformly distributed random variables i.i.d.

a)  Find the cumulative function and the density of $m_n \text{ and } M_n$ , where $m_n=min(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ and $M_n=max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$.

b)  Let $Z_n=n(1-M_n)$. Show that $Z_n \xrightarrow{d} Z $, where $Z$ is a random variable with cumulative function $F_Z(z)=1-e^{-z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_i\rightarrow f$ Then,
$$ $$

\begin{eqnarray}
F_{M_n}(x)&=& \mathbb{P}\{\omega:M_n(\omega)= \max(X_i(\omega))\leq x\}\\
&=& \mathbb{P}\{\omega:\forall ~i~X_i(\omega))\leq x\}
\\&\overset{i.i.d}{=}&\prod \mathbb{P}\{\omega:X_i(\omega)\leq x\}
\\& = & f(x)^n
\end{eqnarray}
On the other hand,
\begin{eqnarray}
F_{m_n}(x)&=& \mathbb{P}\{\omega:m_n(\omega)= \min(X_i(\omega))\leq x\}\\
&=& 1-\mathbb{P}\{\omega:m_n(\omega)= \min(X_i(\omega))\geq x\}\\
&=&1- \mathbb{P}\{\omega:\forall ~i~X_i(\omega))\geq x\}
\\&\overset{i.i.d}{=}&1-\prod \mathbb{P}\{\omega:X_i(\omega)\geq x\}
\\& = & 1-(1-f(x))^n.
\end{eqnarray}
The last question easily follows since 
\begin{eqnarray}
F_{Z_n}(x)&=& \mathbb{P}\{\omega:Z_n(\omega)= n(1-M_n)(\omega)\leq x\}\\
&=& 1-F_{M_n}(1-\frac{x}{n}) = 1-[f(1-\frac{x}{n})]^n
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

a). The CMF are
\begin{align}
F_{M_n}(x)&=P(\{\omega:M_n(\omega)<x\})
\\
&=P(\{\omega:X_1(\omega)<x\}\cap\cdots\cap\{\omega:X_n(\omega)<x\})
\\
&=P(\{\omega:X_1(\omega)<x\})\cdots P(\{\omega:X_n(\omega)<x\})
\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^nF_{X_k}(x)
\\
&=F_{X}^n(x)\tag{if $X_n$ is i.i.d}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
F_{m_n}(x)&=P(\{\omega:m_n(\omega)<x\})
\\
&=P(\{\omega:X_1(\omega)<x\}\cup\cdots\cup\{\omega:X_n(\omega)<x\})
\\
&=1-P(\{\omega:X_1(\omega)<x\}^c\cap\cdots\cap\{\omega:X_n(\omega)<x\}^c)
\\
&=1-P(\{\omega:X_1(\omega)>x\}\cap\cdots\cap\{\omega:X_n(\omega)>x\})
\\
&=1-\prod_{k=1}^nP(X_k>x)
\\
&=1-\prod_{k=1}^n(1-F_{X_k}(x))
\\
&=1-(1-F_{X}(x))^n\tag{if $X_n$ is i.i.d}
\end{align}
The density are
$$
f_{M_n}(x)=F_{M_n}'(x)=nF_{X}^{n-1}(x)f_X(x)
$$
$$
f_{m_n}(x)=F_{m_n}'(x)=n(1-F_{X}(x))^{n-1}f_X(x)
$$
Here $F_{X_n}(x)=x$ for $X_n$ is uniformly distributed random variables. So
$$
F_{M_n}(x)=x^n, \quad F_{m_n}(x)=1-(1-x)^n
$$

b).
$$
F_{Z_n}(z)=P(n(1-M_n)<z)=P(M_n>1-\frac{z}{n})=1-\left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)^n\to1-e^{-z}
$$
Last step uses the facts:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=\frac1{e}\quad\text{and} \quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)^{n/z}\right)^z=e^{-z}
$$
Thus $Z_n\xrightarrow{d} Z$, where $Z$ is a random variable with cumulative function  $F_Z(z)=1-e^{-z}$.